# how to add/connect a new edge to nodes via drag and drop - cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

How can I add a new edge to connect 2 nodes via drag and drop? I would like to drag/draw a new edge from node x to node y manually via mouse.

It would be greatful, if you could give a working example in jsfiddle or something like that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

App-level features should be written in your own app code or in an extension.

Have you taken a look at the [extensions](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions)?

There are two extensions on the list thus far for this usecase.

Cytoscape.js is very extensible, so it's easy to write your own extension if you want something different.

Comment: thank you maxkfranz! the extention edgehandles looks good! https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-edgehandles